# How to remove the selected item from Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>> in android

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I am using `Arraylist < HashMap< String, String >>` in ListView to archive multi-column(I just need two column, so I use HashMap). But when I am using remove method in context menu. It would always remove the last item in the list.

The code:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.bc_contextmenu_delete:
            list.remove(info.position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem to remove the selected one from the list?

Besides, I would also like to get those two values from the HashMap which in the ArrayList. Which code should I use here.

Here is an ArrayList:

```
PS4 4000<br>
PS5 5000<br>
XBOX 6000<br>
```

I would like to get PS4 and 4000.

Thanks all.

Comment: why arraylist contains hashmap? if you have a requirement to store list of key value details, hashmap is enough.

Comment: because I need a multi-column listview. The normal listview just contain one string each line. Here I need to have a listview which can contain more than one string. Just like the example I show above. PS4 is a string, and 4000 is another string. They should show in the same line in the listview

Comment: I think as per your requirement take a new java bean class with no of field instead of map. like example person name and salary so may be new column added in future so you have to add one extra field only in that.

Answer (score 0):

No need to wrap the HashMap into an ArrayList. HashMap itself is enough. If you want to remain the order, you should use [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).
A side effect is that you cannot access elements by index, so you have to iterate over it to get the last item or the one by index.

So if you don't care about duplicates I would use ArrayList with as template a Pair or a custom Object. (Where I prefer a custom object to be more readable)

```
ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> consoles = new ArrayList<Pair<String,int>>();
consoles.Add(Pair.create("PS4", 4000));
consoles.Add(Pair.create("PS5 ", 5000));
consoles.Add(Pair.create("XBOX ", 6000));
```

And remove using index:

```
consoles.Remove(index);
```

Comment: That seems is a easy way. But I don't know how to put it into the listview adapter. I have a question that's if I can put it to the listiview, is it easy to get the values and edit them? How to do that? I suppose it is a list, I should add new item to the list anytime. Many Thanks! I am a beginner in android. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can create a bean for same. i.e. DummyBean. it has two field like

```
class DummyBean{
String name;
String val;

--getter setter method
}
```

Use it into `List<DummyBean>`.
In future if new column added than it is easy to add and expandable.

Comment: So, if I create a new class with two field. Next I should put a class into an ArrayList right? that is ArrayList<class>, then how to assign that two things into the ArrayList? Besides, I have the main problem that's I don't know how to show those two values in the same line in ListView. Many thanks! I am sorry about asking those stupid problem, but I actually is a beginner of writing android. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

To store and retrieve your values from the Hashmap in ArrayList, You need to store the the HashMap values with keys to identify them

As with your example ,

PS4 4000
PS5 5000
XBOX 6000

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String ,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // to add item
    HashMap<String ,String> val = new HashMap<>();
    val.put("GAME", "PS4");
    val.put("NUMBER", "4000");
    list.add(val); //added to 0th index position

    val = new HashMap<>();
    val.put("GAME", "PS5");
    val.put("NUMBER", "5000");
    list.add(val); //added to 1st

    // to retrieve ps4 and 400
    String forPS4 = list.get(0).get("GAME");
    String for4000 = list.get(0).get("4000");
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot!, i can store and retrieve value right now. But now the big problem is I don't know how to remove one line as I selected. That's when I tap PS4, a context menu will be shown. There are two options: Edit and Delete. It is the reason why I ask for retrieving value, that's for edit part. But for delete part, if I want to delete PS4, it would always delete XBOX. I wonder if I got a problem of HashMap, the order of HashMap. Thanks again!